# Purpose of reference indirection in Python

Tags: python

I came across this [python script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/blob/master/2-structured-data/bookshelf/model_datastore.py) and cannot understand the purpose of a certain coding approach.

On line 19, it says `builtin_list = list`

And then on line 43 `if isinstance(entity, builtin_list):`

Why could line 43 simply not use list itself, instead of declaring it as a new builtin_list variable and then use it?

Answer (score 3):

At line [53](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/blob/master/2-structured-data/bookshelf/model_datastore.py#L52), the mentioned code implements the very bad idea of redefining `list` as:

```
def list(limit=10, cursor=None):
```

So having made this mistake, they then need to implement what you are asking about.  Without the mentioned mistake, you would not have been confused.  And then this question would have not been needed.

Comment: i was thinking the same thing